# Force user to agree to Privacy Policy and Terms of Service

Tags: google-oauth

We have a Terms of Service and Privacy Policy on our oauth application, however new users do not have to agree to our Terms & Privacy because we don't require any elevated permissions.

Our oauth has been verified by google, however the consent screen where the user explicitly agrees to elevated permissions and Terms/Service does not come up unless we require additional scope (other than profile, email).

For an example, if you go to www.dropbox.com and authenticate via Google, you'll see the consent screen where they require the user to accept that they will Manage contact list, as well as they need to agree to the Terms and Service. We don't have any elevated permissions so the consent screen doesn't come up, however we need the users to accept the Terms and Service regardless.

Workaround is to just include some random elevated permission, but we'd like to avoid that if possible. Anyone know how we can force the consent screen to show with only the Terms/Service links without having any elevated Google permissions?

Comment: With "sencond" you mean the "consent screen" ?

Comment: yeah, will edit

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [OAuth](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en), which will prompt the customer with a consent screen. The users have to agree to the terms presented on the [consent screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#userconsent).

Otherwise, you can use an in-house solution, that's basically a home landing that requires that they read and click agree on your terms and conditions before allowing them access.

Comment: unfortunately we're not seeing consent screen for new users, because we don't have any elevated permissions that require consent.